# USB Flash Drive shows empty but definitely had non-hidden files

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, fat32, file-recovery

I have this 16 GB USb Flash Drive and I remember storing a lot of data in it. I used this several weeks later on my Windows PC and it fails to show any files on it. None were hidden and even so, my PC has showing hidden folder options enabled. It seems to occupy 9.8 GB at least.

I'm now using this from an ubuntu desktop and it's the same. It's FAT32.

I always made sure to eject safely but it happened anyway.

I'm afraid to make changes to the drive fearing it will overwrite existing data (in case the file system screws up). Are there any file recovery method that will help, for Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you able to try another machine to read the files?

Comment: @Robuust Yes on an Windows PC earlier. It's the same. Shows there are 9.8 GB of data in it. But I don't see the file.

Comment: @SamikSengupta: If you display hidden and system files do the files show up? If not try a few data recovery programs, such as TestDisk, Recuva and the like. If you want you can image the drive using *dd* in Linux or similar on Windows before attempting data recovery. Edit: I see you've [already tried](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307670/access-usb-flash-drive-from-wine) those?

Comment: @Karan  Yes I already did.